# matplolibを使わないどっと絵描きについて

Tags: python

`10*10` のマス目に対して,　位置(0,…99，以下参考)のリストを入力として受取り，`*` を対応する位置に表示する関数 `print_dots` を作成せよ．という問題が分かりません。

0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9     point_dots([0,1])→* *
10 ・・・・・・・・19           　　　　
20　・・・・・・・ 29
・
・
・
90 ・ ・ ・・・・ ・ 99

という感じで,10×10の行列で、対応するところに `*` を打つということです。ご教示いただけると幸いです。

Answer (score 1):

```py
import random

N = 10
def point_dots(points):
    board = [' '] * N**2
    for p in points: board[p] = '*'
    print(f'  {" ".join(map(str, range(N)))}')
    print('\n'.join(f'{i} {" ".join(r)}' for i, r in enumerate(zip(*[iter(board)]*N))))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    points = random.sample(range(100), k=7)
    print(points)
    point_dots(points)
```